# Xamarin duplicated Subscribe when clicking notification

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application with a class that derives from GcmServiceBase, used for retrieving notifcations in Android.

The OnMessage method on this class includes the following code:

```
    string messageText = intent.Extras.GetString("message");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageText))
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<INotifier, AlertModel>
            (this, "myalert", new AlertModel(messageText));
        CreateNotification("this is a notification...", messageText, context);
    }

    private void CreateNotification(string title, string desc, Context context)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        const int pendingIntentId = 0;
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(desc)
            .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);

        var notification = builder.Build();            
        var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        const int notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
    }
```

But this is causing an issue. When I click the notification from the status bar it is creating the pages again, and thus the subscriber to the alert is subscribed more than once.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<INotifier, AlertModel> (this, "myalert", 
(s,arg) => { //Handle });
```

My question is how I would get hold of the existing instance of the page, rather than creating a new one each time? Or if there is a best practise in handling pages - should I make all pages some kind of Singleton or something? Or some other way around this?

Comment: The issue seems to be that you subscribe multiple times during the life-time of your application (which in general with android devices is until you reboot the device). So either unsubscribe when "exiting" or make sure the code is called once during the application's life cycle.

Comment: What would be best practice/ a nice pattern for only subscribing once in the app's lifetime? Some kind of static catalogue of subscriptions? Or would you keep it linked to the class/page that is dealing with it more closely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The trick was to add LaunchMode as SingleTop in the MainActivity class, like so:

```
    [Activity (Label = "MyApp", LaunchMode =LaunchMode.SingleTop, Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
```

And then to pass the intent sent from the onMessage request when creating the PendingIntent of the Notification. So the CreateNotification method now looks like:

```
        private void CreateNotification(string title, string desc, Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentText(desc)
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);

            var notification = builder.Build();            
            var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            const int notificationId = 0;
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);   
        }
```

This means that the main activity is not created anew each time:

> The difference from ‘standard’ is, if an instance of activity already exists at the top of the current task and system routes intent to this activity, no new instance will be created because it will fire off an onNewIntent() method instead of creating a new object. Let’s take the Twitter-oauth integration as example. https://www.mobomo.com/2011/06/android-understanding-activity-launchmode/